# Announcing Your Moderator Pro Tempore Election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Tezos Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **February 25** to bring in three moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Between now and February 25, users can decide whether to nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- During the nomination period, users may nominate themselves and answer any questions that might have been asked on meta.
- On March 4, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on March 12.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: I would like to be a candidate, is this message sufficient ? Our domain is still very young i doubt a lot of our users come very often to meta so i suppose we can advertise this to them directly.

Comment: @Ezy I assume the first link will open up with options to nominate after February 25th.

Comment: @Frank ah thanks i had misunderstood the first bullet point

Comment: @Ezy: I think I misworded it. (I'm pretty sure I'd adjusted the wording a few times.)